# Private streaming session on Twitch.tv

Tags: privacy, video-streaming, twitch.tv

I like the video editing of Twitch and the ability to instantly upload from Twitch to YouTube. I'm planning on testing something for Gaming.SE but since this is more of a test, I think it's not really something that other people have to see. (At least live. The cut version is fine.)

Can I somehow make the streaming session private?

<sub>Basically just for streaming the video onto the Twitch.tv platform for editing.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There is currently no way to do a private stream on Twitch.

As an alternative, [you could use YouTube to host your private livestream](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106770/60818).